# Как считать частоту процессора

Tags: linux, cpu, intel

Есть сервер с таким процессором
https://ark.intel.com/ru/products/83356/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E5-2630-v3-20M-Cache-2_40-GHz, в спецификации прописан турбобуст до 3.2ГГц.

для всех ядер вывод команд одинаков.

`cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/cpuinfo_min_freq`

1200000

`cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/cpuinfo_max_freq`

3200000

`cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor`

performance

если делаю что-либо затратное на одном ядре, то 
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_cur_freq выводит значения равное около 3.2Ггц

если делаю что-либо, что грузит все 32 ядра
то для каждого ядра получаю
`cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_cur_freq`

2.6Ггц
(ожидал тоже получить 3.2Ггц)

Я мог бы предположить, что общий буст не работает для логических ядер, и просто считается размазанным по всем ядрам. но тогда бы получалось что частота каждого 
(3200-2400)*16/32 + 2400 ~ 2.8Ггц

Comment: А в код посмотреть?

Comment: А кто сказал, что процессор при загрузке всех ядер разгонится на максимум, может он считает, что ему не хватит энергии или теплоотдачи для полного разгона всех ядер на максимум и он принимает решение разгонять их не полностью

Comment: нет никакого кода.
taskset -c 0 /dev/urandom

cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_cur_freq

3192375


for i in {0..31}
do
  taskset -c $i md5sum /dev/urandom &
done

для каждого ядра вывод

cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/cpuinfo_cur_freq

2599968

Comment: Вы меня не поняли, посмотрите в код ядра сами.

Comment: турбо работает только на одном ядре

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Turbo Boost` увеличивает частоту загруженного ядра - любого ядра процессора. Поэтому `cpuinfo_max_freq` рапортует идентичные значения. Максимальная частота в спецификации указывается для загрузки одного ядра.

При утилизации всех ядер частота каждого из ядер должна быть не ниже базовой, т.е. 2,4ГГц (если нет проблем с охлаждением, тогда частота может быть снижена для защиты от перегрева). В вашем случае процессор очевидно посчитал, что на 2,6ГГц так же помещается в свой теплопакет и следовательно ему допустимо работать на частоте 2,6ГГц.

При утилизации части ядер частота так же будет плавать где-то между 2,4 и 3,2ГГц.

В общем, давно уже нет статичной частоты процессора. Он сам меняет частоту [в зависимости](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/turbo-boost/turbo-boost-technology.html/index.htm) от:

- загрузки
- количества активных ядер
- оценки потребления энергии и тепловыделения
- своей температуры